A general approach to a specific type of borrowing conflict problem in Rust
When writing Rust, I often encounter a similar issue that leads to compilation errors, specifically mutable borrow conflicts (E0502). I have simplified it into the following form:
pub struct Foo{
    // omits fields
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_val(&self, idx: usize) -> usize {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct Bar{
    // omits fields
}

pub struct Baz{
    foo: Vec<Foo>,
    bar: Bar
}

impl Baz{
    fn get_foo(&self, idx: usize)->&Foo {
        todo!()
    }

    fn bar_insert(&mut self, val: usize) -> usize{
        // use &mut self.bar
        todo!()
    }

    fn some_op(&self, foo: &Foo, val: usize){
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, idx: usize){
        let foo = self.get_foo(idx);  // line 1
        let val = foo.get_val(idx);  // line 2
        let val2 = self.bar_insert(val); // line 3
        self.some_op(foo, val2); // line 4
    }

}

Suppose this is a lib code, and the ultimate goal is to provide users the ability to insert a piece of data using Baz::insert. Baz consists of data of two types, Foo and Bar. The code will compile with error E0502 because the insert method borrows self immutably in the 1st line, and the borrow's lifetime lasts until the end of the method. Meanwhile, in the 3rd line, self is borrowed mutably, causing a conflict.
However, I know that bar_insert only modifies the bar field and does not affect foo in any way.
In this case, the 4th line cannot be moved up because the some_op method depends on the value returned in the previous step.
My questions:
Does this compilation error genuinely reflect some design flaw in my code, or is it a limitation of Rust's current state?
Is there a general approach to solve such problems?
Previously, in such situations, I have either used unsafe raw pointers, RefCell, or clone, but none of these seem like the most appropriate solution.

Why is this an error?
Rust will not make assumptions about what your function does, even if the current code could work in the case you've shown. The reason being Rust has an emphasis on backwards compatibility and tracking what a function does makes updating functionality impossible. Rust only follows the signatures of functions for it's requirements promises, if it introspected functions to determine what fields are accessed it would balloon complexity. I believe I saw an RFC to add a field access list to the function signature but I can't find it now.
What to do about it?
Rust doesn't allow conflicting method calls at the same time but it does allow independent field access to overlap. What this means is that you don't need to clone or do unsafe code to call both methods, they instead must not take self. There are a few ways to do this:
Static Functions
This would be replacing your self functions with static functions:
impl Baz {
    // We use a slice here since a ref to a `Vec` is the same as a slice in most cases
    fn get_foo(foo: &[Foo], idx: usize) -> &Foo {
        todo!()
    }

    fn bar_insert(bar: &mut Bar, val: usize) -> usize {
        // use &mut self.bar
        todo!()
    }

    // I don't know if you actually need both, but let's say you do.
    fn some_op(bar: &mut Bar, s_foo: &[Foo], foo: &Foo, val: usize) {
        todo!()
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, idx: usize) {
        let foo = Self::get_foo(&self.foo, idx);
        let val = foo.get_val(idx);
        let val2 = Self::bar_insert(&mut self.bar, val);
        Self::some_op(&mut self.bar, &self.foo, foo, val2);
    }
}

This works well for smaller structs. As a side note unless these functions are being used across many functions, unroll them into the larger function. If you're making many one time functions it's indicative of bad type design as I describe in the next section.
Functions on Members
These functions in your example should exist on the member fields if they only access a single field. You can always forward in the wrapping type to the lower types for your public interface, but your example shows the functions as non-public.
impl Bar {
    pub fn insert(val: usize) -> usize {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Baz {
    fn get_foo(&self, idx: usize)->&Foo {
        // Use the vec func. Probably should be
        // get and return and option but I'll keep 
        // the panic api from the example.
        &self.foo[idx]
    }

    fn bar_insert(&mut self, val: usize) -> usize {
        self.bar.insert(val)
    }

    // Unroll this
    // fn some_op(&self, foo: &Foo, val: usize) {
    //    todo!()
    // }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, idx: usize) {
        let foo = &self.foo[idx];
        let val = foo.get_val(idx);
        let val2 = self.bar.insert(val);
        todo!(); // Unroll `some_op` here
    }
}

If you're accessing a subset of fields it usually means either your type is too complex (methods usually access all the fields at the right level of abstraction) or the method is not complex enough (only doing a subset of the work) in which case you should static it.
